# Askpass Program in Java

Tags: java, swing, process

I was wondering how to write an `askpass` program in Java. I want to be able to use `sudo` in a Java `Process`, but I get an error telling me to make an `askpass` program.

I want to get the password from a `JTextField` (`Swing`) and give it to a `Process`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by having the user type their `sudo` password and executing the command like so:

`outputStreamWriter.write((useSudo.isSelected() ? " echo " + sudoPass + " | sudo -S " : "") + command);`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use sudo from within a script or a java program without configuring sudoers. You need to have the following setting in /etc/sudoers

```
Defaults:<username> !requiretty
```

Where username is the owner of the Java process. Also you probably don't want to be prompted for a password. So you want the -n option

```
sudo -n <mycommand>
```

In order for that to work you may need further configurations to on /etc/sudoers. The secure way to do it tend to be very specific to the command that you are trying to run. A quick and dirty solution is to have the following in /etc/sudoers

```
user <username>=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Would any user of my program need to do this?

Comment: You asked how you can fork a process from a JVM and that the new process should run as sudo. The above settings will allow that. Others I don't think you will be able to start a process from within Java code using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner to get you started:

```
System.out.println(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, args[0], "AskPass", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));
```

Comment: As I said, I want to use a `JTextField` I already have. Also, all that does is pop up a message with a place to input a password. It doesn't give the password to the `Process`.

Comment: As far as I know, askpass is invoked as a separate process, by the program asking for a password. I don't think you can make it "go back into your program". One thing you can do is set up some kind of communication between the 2 processes, e.g. using sockets.